# How can I generate GN benchmark graphs for community detection in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using R and igraph package to detect communities in graphs, but I haven't found a precise way of creating graphs with community features like the ones used in several papers about community detection.

I wish I could generate graphs using [Girvan-Newman benchmark](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.4770v4.pdf), so I could specify the  `k_out` and `k_in` variables (the degree of links outside and inside the communities, respectively) and create such graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stochastic blockmodel, http://igraph.org/r/doc/sample_sbm.html.

Comment: Great! I've easily adapted sbm.game to create community structured graphs. I'd like to compare the community detection algorithms I'm developing, but I would need to know which node belongs to which community so I can compare it using Normalized Mutual information (`compare(comm1,comm2,method="nmi")`), do you know how can I do that?

Comment: See http://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html and http://igraph.org/r/doc/compare.communities.html. If you need more help with these, then please start a new question.

Comment: I think @JonCardoso wants to know how to retrieve the ground truth corresponding to the block structure in the generated graph. From what I understand, the blocks are created in a contiguous way: the first n_1 nodes constitute the first block, the next n_2 nodes are the second block, and so on (where n_k is the size of block k). I know this comment comes a bit late, but it may be useful to other users!

Answer (score 0):

The above link (http://igraph.org/r/doc/sbm.game.html) doesn't work correctly.
However, there is a LFR benchmark, which generalize the GN benchmark, available for this purpose. We can find it on https://sites.google.com/site/santofortunato/inthepress2.

The graph outputs of the benchmark can be imported directly into R by functions such as read.table or read.csv. The community information is also available as output of the benchmark. Hence, the community comparision function can be used.